# AngularJS filter by property which name is expanded from a variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an `ng-repeat` attribute with this filter

```
ng-repeat="offer in Offers.full | filter: { IdOffer: Filter.value } | orderBy: Order.type+Order.column track by offer.IdDeal
```

Pretty straightforward: the array of objects is contained in `$scope.Offers.full`, the property name selected for "order by" is stored in `$scope.Order.column` (and `$scope.Order.type` add a `+` or `-` to switch from ascending to descending), the filter on `"IdOffer"` property is in  `$scope.Filter.value`.

Now I want to filter `$scope.Filter.value` not on `"IdOffer"` property but on a property witch name is stored in `$scope.Filter.column` variable. Is it possible something like this?

```
| filter: { Filter.column: Filter.value }
```

Comment: Have you tried this approach already ?

Comment: @UmairFarooq of course I did

Comment: Did you ever try the solution I provided?

Comment: @Lex sorry I didn't. To create a custom filter is an option but I was looking for an "already in place" method and I finally decided to create a `$scope.filterObj` object where to add attributes dinamically, then I passed it to the filter `| filter: filterObj`.
Your solution seem to work as well, but I can't test it right now because I don't have access to the repository with the code I wrote

Comment: Ah, gotcha. One benefit of creating it as a custom filter is that you'd be able to use it in other locations of your app, but if that's not a consideration then doing the filtering in the controller is probably good enough.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to write a custom filter for this, but it's pretty easy. Here's a sample that will do a case-insensitive filter similar to the filtering that's baked into Angular:

```
.filter('customFilter', function() {
    return function(input, filterColumn, filterValue) {
        if(!filterColumn || !filterValue) {
            return input;
        }
        var out = [];
        angular.forEach(input, function(item) {
            // convert numbers to strings so partial numbers can be matched as well
            var columnValue = angular.isNumber(item[filterColumn])
                ? item[filterColumn].toString()
                : item[filterColumn].toLowerCase();
            if(columnValue.includes(filterValue.toLowerCase())) {
                out.push(item);
            }
        });
        return out;
    }
})
```

You would use it as follows:

```
| customFilter:Filter.column:Filter.value
```